# Sorted Trie data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie, word-count

I have a requirement to track the occurrence of the words in the text and this occurrence need to be arranged in the descending order. I initially used the hash map data structure however as I was researching further on, I discovered the "Trie" data structure.

I think "Trie" data structure is perfect for tracking the occurrence in terms of both flexibility and complexity. However there is one more requirements, I need to sort the occurrence in descending order. So basically traversing the "Trie" in depth first search.

Implementation wise this is little tricky, so I was wondering if I was in the right track. 
Any kind of opinion would be great. What would be the best data structure to use in this case?

Note: Sort order is descending in terms of occurrence so if "A" appeared 5 times and "B" appeared 2 times sort order should be "A", "B". Also two words with same occurrences would be sorted in alphabetical order.

Thanks

Comment: Descending in terms of the alphabetical (Z-A) order of the words in the trie? or descending in terms of number of occurrences of a particular word in the Trie?

Comment: [Yes, that sounds like a decent idea.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202122/how-should-we-handle-am-i-correct-questions-when-theyre-correct)

Comment: I updated the above with what sort means. Do you have any suggestion on what to use when implementing this data structure?

Comment: You can try the trie implementation at https://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/

Comment: By the way, reading your question again, I doubt the sort order you require can be obtained "for free" by using any smart data structure. Using a map (bst, trie or hash) and then sorting according to the frequency is still your best bet I believe.

Comment: And just to clarify: do you need to read the whole input and **then** output the frequency, or do you need to output the frequencies **while** you read the text, maybe because the text can grow over time (online problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefixes of the **words are repeatable**, the **trie tree** will be most memory-efficient solution, unfortunately still O(N) pessimistically. You'll need to enrich the standard trie-tree class with additional information - words counters.

If you're looking for pessimistically optimal solution, multimap is a better solution:

- O(1) insert time (not in trie tree if you have alphabet with many letters)
- O(N) memory and running time

Still, you'll need to sort the words within the same occurrence count bucket, if there're many words with the same occurrence number, sorting becomes the dominant operation, and trie-tree approach is the same as multimap approach.

Answer (score 2):

the main property of `trie` is to merge the incoming data to save space, so if you want to use any property which is individual to any of the data unit, you can not benefit from the `trie` built in properties. So you can think if you want to save space, use `trie`, but to get the most frequent word, somehow you need to use some other algorithm (like traversing the `trie` once the data has been collected and prepare another table).

My idea is probably `priority queue` with the frequency of the word as the key can be a possible candidate

Comment: There is no reason to use a priority queue IMHO: the time complexity will still be O(N lgN) because you perform N insertion/bubble up or down in the priority queue (by the way only insertion is supported by the java implementation). At this point you are better off reading the whole input, dumping the key/frequency in an array and then sort by frequency/key. Unless of course this is an "online" problem, in which case the priority queue (with bubbling!) is the best choice.

Comment: true, that's why I mentioned `like traversing the trie once the data has been collected and prepare another table`, problem is OP did not mentioned many necessary details, so we are probably just making guesses :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary trie but the insertion time is expensive but you can skip the sort algorithm when you are just interested in the top 5 most occurrence words.